# Problem with regular expression matching order in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have the following sample text

```
The quick brown {fox} jumps over the lazy {dog}
```

I need to match any string enclosed in {} which can occur several times in the text.
I tried the following code but it doesn't work properly

```
<?php

$matches = array();

$string = "The quick brown {fox} jumps over the lazy {dog}";

preg_match("/\{(.*)\}/",$string,$matches);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

and that's what I get

```
Array
(
    [0] => {fox} jumps over the lazy {dog}
    [1] => fox} jumps over the lazy {dog
)
```

I would expect getting

```
Array
(
    [0] => {fox} jumps over the lazy {dog}
    [1] => fox
    [2] => dog
)
```

So how can I force PHP to match the nearest "}" instead of matching the last one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your existing regex has `.*` which is **greedy** and tries to consume **as much as possible**. To fix this you need to make the regex **non-greedy** by adding a `?` at the end as:

```
.*?
```

alternatively you can also use `[^}]*` in place of `.*`.

And since you want all matches, you need to use `preg_match_all`

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/lzv1v)

Comment: That works great. Would you please explain the usage of ? in this case ? Is this usage documented ?

Comment: The ? is a standard feature of regular expressions: see http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html for details on greediness/laziness

Answer (score 0):

By default, your regexp is executed in greedy mode. You need ungreedy. Either use the /U switch, or codaddict's suggestion of *.? to make that part of the expression ungreedy

Answer (score 0):

By default, expressions are greedy, i.e., they try to grab the longest possible matches. You can make an expression ungreedy with the `U` flag:

```
preg_match('/\{(.*)\}/U', $string, $matches);
```